# Alliging values within a single column in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My select statement looks like this:

```
select RPAD(label,40) || count (*) from table
```

My result looks like this:

```
label             1
otherlabel       3
anotherlabel    0
```

How can I get my `count()` number to line up?
I have tried using various combination of *LPAD* and *RPAD* but because the text characters are not of set width , the numbers are allways slightly off.
anyone have a trick for this?

So I want :

```
label           1
otherlabel      3
anotherlabel    0
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: .Is the application that is displaying the result using a proportional font?  Or a fixed width font?  Is there a reason that you wouldn't select this as two columns rather than one?  And I'm assuming that your actual `SELECT` statement has a `GROUP BY`

Comment: I'm wondering if you've hidden your real problem by trying to simplify it (not least because of the zero count). Do you actually have counts that are of different orders of magnitude, and the numbers are coming out left-aligned? Maybe you can add some actual data and output that shows the problem you are really seeing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a font problem. Use a monospaced font (where all letters have the same width) in your app and you are done.

Comment: I don't have admin access to the oracle server

Comment: This has nothing to do with your database system. This is about the program you use to show data, such as TOAD, SQL Developer, a report engine, a program written by yourself or a colleague, ...

Comment: And as Justin Cave commented: what you are doing is somewhat rare. Usually you simply select two columns and show them in a grid, so alignment is no problem.